# Laravel 5.3 query builder access violation on group by

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel-5.3, laravel-query-builder

I have been using Laravel 5 for a week and I've now come to the point where I want to convert all my existing raw SQL queries using Query Builder but I have a problem.

When I run the following query, I get this error message

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055
>   'procurement.pp_proposals.title' isn't in GROUP BY

```
$proposals = DB::table('tableA')
                ->join('tableB', 'tableA.id', '=', 'tableB.id')
                ->leftJoin('tableC', 'tableA.id', '=', 'tableC.id')
                ->select(DB::raw('tableA.id, title, date_created, date_completed, percent_complete, complete, COALESCE(COUNT(tableC.id), 0) AS total_ids'))
                ->where([
                    ['tableB.user', '=', Auth::user()->username],
                    ['submitted', '=', '0'],
                ])
                ->groupBy('tableA.id')
                ->orderBy('title', 'asc')
                ->get();
```

This is my raw SQL that works perfectly fine so I don't understand why i need to GROUP BY on all the extra columns

```
SELECT tableA.id, 
        title,
        date_created,
        date_completed,
        percent_complete,
        complete,
        COALESCE(COUNT(tableC.id), 0) AS 'total_ids'
FROM tableA
    INNER JOIN tableB
        ON tableA.id = tableB.id
    LEFT JOIN tableC
        ON tableA.id = tableC.id
WHERE submitted = '0' AND tableB.user = 'user' 
GROUP BY tableA.id
ORDER by title ASC
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure how it works but surely you can fix that issue by setting `strict = false` on the `config/database.php` file to your MySQL config!

I had the same issue and setting it to false solve my problem!

Actually I just opened a question here to find why it happens!

If you want to follow: [Strict database config Laravel 5.2 to Laravel 5.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41719556/strict-database-config-laravel-5-2-to-laravel-5-3)